# CMake - how to block executing installation scripts during packaging?

Tags: cmake, cpack

My `CMakeLists.txt` file contains commands, which should be executed by `make install`, and all this works fine. The sample `CMakeLists.txt` below is a short excerpt from my actual CMake file (the `tm0001.cpp` content is not important here - it might be any C++ program):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(tm0001)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} tm0001.cpp)

install(
  TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  DESTINATION /usr/local/bin
  PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
)

install(CODE "message(\"-- This must be called during installation only\")")

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "HEKTO")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
include(CPack)
```

I see the `message` command is executed by `make package` as well, which is *not* I want.

How to tell CMake *not* to execute installation scripts by the `make package` command? I couldn't find any way to do that with the CMake `if` command.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal `CMakeLists.txt` that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @compor - done, thanks

Comment: From a packagers point of view I think it is a bad idea to change the state of the system when installing a package. Maybe instead add a message that the admin should restart the daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, because the existing answer doesn't address my main problem. I couldn't find any way (on the CMake level) to block `install` commands from running during `make package` - even the `postinst` script is called by this command.

Fortunately, I could modify the `postinst` script itself to do nothing in case it's called **not by** the dpkg:

```
if [ -z ${DPKG_ADMINDIR} ]; then
  echo "postinst: missing 'dpkg' environment (not an error during packaging)"
  exit 0
fi
```

It's a trick of course, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

As it already said in the comment, it's an extremely bad idea to "work w/ `systemd`" (and doing anything not related to build or packaging of your project) from `install` commands. The `install` command (even `SCRIPT` and `CODE` signatures) **are intended to be used for install actions** and not for any *other side effects*.

The correct way to act here is to produce a native package (DEB/RPM) w/ post-install script, where using the system-provided macros (like described [here](https://people.debian.org/~stapelberg/debconf13-making-your-package-work-with-systemd.pdf)), you can install your package properly. Take a look to [`CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPackDeb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA) for the way to provide package install actions.

The other bad thing is to use the hardcoded path (`/usr/bin/`). And BTW, a better place for the (pure) daemon app I suggest `/usr/sbin/`. Take a look to [`GNUInstallDirs`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) module shipped w/ CMake for further references.

Comment: I was asking about CMake *only*, the `systemctl` call is just an example. In reality I do a lot of various things during installation by `cmake` and by `dpkg` - but I don't want to do these things during packaging. If CMake can't do that, that's a problem with CMake, but not with my question. The `/usr/bin` directory usage is also an example, I could use any other directory.

Comment: The point is not to do anything that is not related to build or packaging process from CMake configuration. Move your _a lot of various things_ to some helper script or whatever -- it is not a part of your project, obviously, it should be post-install actions of your package. In case you do `sudo make install` locally just do `sudo ./run-post-install.sh` after... and include these actions to Debian control file as well.
But, the true way, is to design your project in a way when you don't need to `make install` it locally! :)

Comment: Yep, it is not a problem w/ your question... It is the problem of your understanding of the development process (w/ CMake %).
Probably I can guess the way to distinct `make install` performed by CPack from manually executed, but it'll be based on implementation details, so can't be considered as a reliable solution to your problem raised as a result of weird usage of CMake %)

Comment: My take from this conversation is that the CMake doesn't allow targets `install` and `package` to coexist nicely

Comment: Do _nice_ things and everything would be _nice_ :) -- doing _dirty_ things ... you know %) For me both targets co-exist pretty well in quite complex projects.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was to specify install commands with CODE/SCRIPT as separate component e.g. install(CODE ... COMPONENT post-install).

Then also added other non-code install commands as a different component e.g. install(FILES ... COMPONENT files-install)

The CPack then needs to be configured to package only files-install component (solution to this can be found easily - hint: use **CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL_IN_ONE_PACKAGE, CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL and CPACK_(RPM/DEB/...)_COMPONENT_INSTALL** variables).

Of course then the resulting package won't run these CODE components during installing the package - they need to be added separately as a post install script.